# CodeAcademy Javascript lesson accepts code but doesn't display expected output

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code snippet in a codeacademy lesson which requires a working "for" or "while" loop. Codeacademy accepts the code as sufficient to complete the lesson, but the console does not output anything. I double-checked all my tokens were matched, declaring my variables inside and outside of question(), and looking at w3schools examples and SE's question forums and I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```js
// Write your loop below!


var question = function(answer){
    var dragonHealth = 10;
    var attack = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var answer = prompt("Wishest thou to smote a terrible beast?", "verrily");
    if (question === "verrily"){
for (dragonHealth; dragonHealth > 0; dragonHealth - attack){
    console.log("You hit the dragon and he suffered " + attack + "damage!");
    
if (dragonHealth <= 0){
    console.log("You hath smote the dragon forthwith, and merrily celebrated thine victory with a picnic at the beach. (Yes, there were fair maidens in attendance.)");
}
}
}
};
question(answer);
```

Comment: Don't you mean, `if (answer === "verrily")`?

Comment: you're passing `answer` as undefined here: `question(answer);` but also you're using it as argument here `function(answer) {` and than inside the function you reinstantiate it using `var answer`.... loot of things to fix.

Comment: also whats the point of passing `answer` into your function?

Comment: Thanks, Pointy. Completely missed that.
iam-decoder, I was hoping to make the lesson a bit more interactive via prompt(), but I went over my head on this one.
Roko, does the prompt() not define answer? whether I add that inside or outside of the function, running the code produces nothing.